# The container image doesn`t support specified OS 'Linux' for container group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I would like to prepare Microsoft container (required framework 4.6) with fileShare but I get error. Do you know what is wrong? and how do it this correct? The container image 'microsoft/aspnet' doesn't support specified OS 'Linux' for container group 'mmsappcalculation-1'.

```
rafal@Azure:~$ # Change these four parameters as needed
rafal@Azure:~$ ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP=mmsAppCalculationGroup
rafal@Azure:~$ ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=fileshare8956
rafal@Azure:~$ STORAGE_KEY=2Ee56ua3I4gU7TgcI3IhAICXhgt+UG0xSL/kb9+PKEGl40T/5rHflEy8DMHwbaFqZL0oMfwzcjyAXDsQDg1Q==
rafal@Azure:~$ ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME=acishare
rafal@Azure:~$
rafal@Azure:~$
rafal@Azure:~$ az container create \
>     --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP \
>     --image microsoft/aspnet \
>     --name mmsappcalculation-1 \
>     --dns-name-label mmsappcalculation \
>     --ports 80 \
>     --azure-file-volume-account-name $ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME \
>     --azure-file-volume-account-key $STORAGE_KEY \
>     --azure-file-volume-share-name $ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME \
>     --azure-file-volume-mount-path /app/sharedFile/
The container image 'microsoft/aspnet' doesn't support specified OS 'Linux' for container group 'mmsappcalculation-1'.
```

before I run this

```
# Change these four parameters as needed
ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP=mmsAppCalculationGroup
ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=fileshare$RANDOM
ACI_PERS_LOCATION=eastus
ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME=acishare

# Create the storage account with the parameters
az storage account create \
    --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --name $ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME \
    --location $ACI_PERS_LOCATION \
    --sku Standard_LRS

# Create the file share
az storage share create \
  --name $ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME \
  --account-name $ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

**update**
I try also like this but still not work

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest

```
>     --os-type Windows \
az: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: az [-h] [--verbose] [--debug] [--only-show-errors]
          [--output {json,jsonc,yaml,yamlc,table,tsv,none}] [--query JMESPATH]
          {container} ...
rafal@Azure:~$     --cpu 2 \
>     --memory 3.5 \
>     --azure-file-volume-mount-path /app/sharedFile/
bash: --cpu: command not found
rafal@Azure:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run .Net core you can use a Linux or Windows Container.
If you want to run .Net Framework you need to use a Windows Container.

microsoft/aspnet uses .Net Framework so you must use a Windows Container to run it.

If you want to try this in Azure App Service, here is our quickstart on how to run a custom Windows container in Azure App Service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container

Comment: ok. I understand but I can not put my app to docker Hub I need create my app from azure command line. I need Windows Container with shared folder and I don`t undrstand where I made mistake in my code (should work correct). I did not add parameter with Windows Container? Why Azure think I have Windows Container image (this correct) but configuration for linux (this wrong)?

Comment: os-typy Window and Window Container not support file share

Comment: Feel free to open a support incident and we will assist
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request