# The container image doesn't support specified OS 'Linux' for container group

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, containers, azure-container-instances

I a trying to deploy the container to azure and it says it doesn't support linux. Below is my docker file code

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY [".csproj", "/"]
COPY [".csproj", "/"]
COPY [".csproj", "/"]
COPY [".csproj", "/"]
COPY [".csproj", "/"]
COPY [".csproj", "/"]
COPY [".csproj", "/"]
COPY [".csproj", "/"]
COPY ["T.csproj", "/"]
RUN dotnet restore "/.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/E"
RUN dotnet build ".csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ".csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EinrideGRPCService.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

***Currently, Azure Container instance does not support some specific image. You could try to create this image on Azure Portal, even you will get same error log like***

```
    {
    "error":{
    "code":"ImageOsTypeNotMatchContainerGroups",
    "message"; "The OS type'<null>'of image 'sagemath/sagemath-jupyter'doesnot match the OS type 'Linux' of container group 'test1'."
    }
    }
```

Azure Container Instances has solution for many scenario operate in isolated containers, and OS containers are suitable with your need. But if your need is only application as components, it doesn't necessary to use OS as your  image

For your scenario, I suggest you could use [Azure Container Service(aks)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/index).

Or

If you want to run .Net core you can use a Linux or Windows Container. If you want to run .Net Framework you need to use a Windows Container. Please refer the following ***SO thread*** for more information

[The container image doesn`t support specified OS 'Linux' for container group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683361/the-container-image-doesnt-support-specified-os-linux-for-container-group)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container?tabs=dot